# Is it possible to have HTML tag <input> display more that the first portion of a string separated by white space?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

My MVC Code only displays "worda", not "worda wordb wordc".

```
@{
    var  myString = "worda wordb wordc";
}
<div class="row">
    <input value=@myString>
</div>
```

The issue appears to be with razors parsing and generating incorrect output. Here is what Razor created:

```
<input value="worda" wordb="" wordc="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the variable `myString` between quotation like this

```
  @{
    var myString = "worda wordb wordc";
  }
  <div class="row">
    <input value="@myString">
  </div>
```